# Ability to lock orientation of device with JavaScript in PhoneGap/Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm looking for a way to programatically lock the orientation of a device in a PhoneGap/Cordova application using JavaScript for certain pages only.

I am aware that in can be locked globally in the config.xml file but I am searching for a solution that supports both iOS and Android whereby I can lock the orientation using a checkbox/radio control on a single page in my App.

I have found some possible Cordova plugins but they are all Android only.

I am willing to write a Cordova/PhoneGap plugin but I am not sure of the Objective-C and Java code required to lock the orientation using the various native API's.

Here is a great example of what I'm looking for (this is Android only but I need support for both iOS & Android):
https://github.com/Hless/cordova-plugin-orientationchanger

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks,
XigenBen

*Remember this plugin only works in android and only if you put this: phonegap.js instead of cordova.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled across a plugin on the Cordova plugin registry that solves this exact issue, here's the URL for anyone interested:
http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/net.yoik.cordova.plugins.screenorientation

Can also be found on GitHub:
https://github.com/yoik/cordova-yoik-screenorientation