# How to lock orientation for only on one page on Mobile App?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, mobile

We are working on hybrid app, so from coding perspective most of the work is only in HTML5, CSS3 and Javascript/JQuery.

Was able to find related bunch of posts on SO

[Orientation Lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410023/orientation-lock)

[How to disable orientation change in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512045/how-to-disable-orientation-change-in-android)

However, we just need to lock orientation on only one page, dont have liberty to add settings in manifest file. Looking for a Javascript/JQuery based solution or an Android plugin that can be invoked using Javascript ?

Comment: You can specify orientation per activity in the Manifest.

Comment: Thanks Bic .. its a hybrid app basically, will try to do this in generated code.

Comment: Cordova might do what you need: http://cordova.apache.org/

Comment: thanks you so much @Bic. checking cordova site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a very simple plugin that can do this job:

[pg-plugin-screen-orientation](https://github.com/their/pg-plugin-screen-orientation)

Very easy to use:

```
To lock the screen to Landscape: navigator.screenOrientation.set('landscape');
To lock the screen to Portrait: navigator.screenOrientation.set('portrait');
To unlock: navigator.screenOrientation.set('fullSensor');
```

Worked for us.

Comment: This plugin is deprecated now, use this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32405615/1848600

Answer (score 0):

You are able to specify orientation per activity in the Android Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.LoginActivity">
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".activities.HomeActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="userLandscape">
</activity>
```

In the above example, the LoginActivity will rotate when the user changes orientation, but the HomeActivity will always be in landscape.

Comment: Thanks.. but need JQuery/Javascript based solution... edited  question with some details.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the orientation of one `Activity` programmatically by calling `setRequestedOrientation()` before calling `setContentView()` in `onCreate()` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    ...
}
```

You can also specify the orientation for one `Activity` in your manifest by adding this:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.ui.MainActivity"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Comment: Thanks.. but need JQuery/Javascript based solution... edited  question with some details.

Comment: @SachinThapa So you are saying you are using Phonegap? Why wouldn't you mention that? And how does my answer not apply even if it is a hybrid app? For such specific things you are going to need to write a plugin for each platform.

Comment: Sorry.. I edited my question later.. whole app is one activity.

Comment: @SachinThapa Then you cannot lock the orientation. You need to set the lock before calling `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`. After that you cannot change it or remove it anymore. You need to start a new `Activity` instance each time you want to change the orientation lock.

Comment: Thanks Xaver for taking out time to respond, yes exactly ! Was looking around to find a Javascript solution for the same reason.

Comment: Well you will not find one, in case my previous comment wasn't clear enough: What you are trying to do is technically impossible on Android.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement for an app. It was not able to lock the orientation but I could detect the orientation change using the "deviceorientation" event which can be handled as `window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", hadlerFunction, true);`. What I did was, I showed an alert prompting the user to change tge orientation.  It was not a hybrid app.
However if you follow this [link][1]

[1]: [Ability to lock orientation of device with JavaScript in PhoneGap/Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22843675/ability-to-lock-orientation-of-device-with-javascript-in-phonegap-cordova) you would get some inputs for your question.

Comment: Thanks @MaheshMG, looking at the link, this might be close to what we want to do.